# Update View based on value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have two tables

### Table 1:

```
    id           Name        item_ref     item_name
----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
    101          abc            1           item1
    102          xyz            2           item2
```

### Table 2:

```
 item_ref     item_name      end_date
----------    ----------    ----------
    1           item1          null
    2           item2         01-AUG-13
    3           item3          null
```

Now i want to create a view with only those items from Table 1 whose items from Table 2 has not expired.

For example, for the above case the result should be

### VIEW - Result

```
    id           Name        item_ref     item_name      end_date
----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
    101          abc            1           item1         null
```

Here 102 is not present as item2 has expired.

Please help 
(Using Oracle)

Comment: This is very basic SQL. Grab any SQL tutorial, read up on JOINs, and this will be a piece of cake.

Comment: We ask questions only if we dont get the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the view!

```
CREATE VIEW schema.view_name AS
  SELECT a.id, a.name, a.item_ref, a.item_name, b.end_date
     FROM table1 a   
          JOIN   
          table2 b
       ON (a.item_ref = b.item_ref)
    WHERE ( b.end_date IS NULL ) OR (b.end_date > SYSDATE ) ;
```

Each time you query the view, the subquery will be executed, thus the view data will be always updated.
Check the ORACLE Language Reference on `CREATE VIEW` for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm